# Insert item on app purchase

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-checkout, android-pay

I have a problem to insert the item to in app billing.
I created the apk, inserting in the manifest permissions billing
I loaded it in the market (I have not published the app, I put it in alpha)
I register for google wallet (given that the checkout is closing)
I go to the page for the products in the app, but I can not add items, and keeps telling me to create a merchant account, and clicking on the link brings me back to home ..
could you tell me what's wrong?

Comment: i hate the "up" but is very important. no one have idea?

Comment: Can you share what is your app going to sell, or where is your site that is using Google Checkout today?

Comment: my app is't public at this moment. why?